# React: Saving data in route when navigating between different routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, history

I try to save data in my route which is persisted when I am navigating between different routes. But the data is lost.

```
const history = useHistory();

const handleSubmit = () => {
    history.push({pathname: '/', state: {
        nsin: props.nsin,
        assetClass: props.assetClass,
        bondsSubclass: props.bondsSubclass,
        expCurrency: props.expCurrency,
        expCountry: props.expCountry,
        instrCategory: props.instrCategory,
        nominal: props.nominal,
        openEnd: props.openEnd,
        callableByIssuer: props.callableByIssuer,
        callableByClient: props.callableByClient
    } });

}

return (
    <button onClick={handleSubmit}>
    Overview
    </button>
);
```

And then I try to access the state like:

```
value={this.props.location?.state?.nsin}
```

Comment: have you tried calling it using the useLocation hook?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Context to have a global state.
[Create Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)